# Negative number to the power of...

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We know that negative number to the power of any integers or some fractions  will always have a solution.  Is it possible for us to solve $(-2)^\frac 13$ or $(-2)^e$, by modifying/extending our current number system?

Comment: Does "our current number system" include the complex numbers?

Comment: I mean in order to make (-2)^e has one absolute definite value

Comment: By which you mean "$(-2)^e$ has no more than a single defined value", correct?

Comment: @abiessu YESS....

Comment: As far as I understand it, you have the option of choosing to ignore the alternate values that something like $(-2)^\frac 13$ can take on (which has a real value at $-\sqrt [3]{2}$), but doing so can make other things that produced the need for this value to be limited in their results and/or produce incorrect or unexpected results.

Comment: @abiessu I don't get it..

Comment: So we have $$(-2)^\frac 13=\left\{-\sqrt[3]{2},\frac{1+i\sqrt 3}{2},\frac{1-i\sqrt 3}{2}\right\}$$ of which the first value is the only value among the reals.  If we ignored the two complex values, we are effectively ignoring two solutions of a cubic polynomial, much like ignoring solutions in the complex numbers to the polynomial $x^2+1$.  It is the case that the solutions do not appear on the real line, but they still exist.

Comment: First the number $(-2)^{e}$ has no sense without a definition, and we can see that it's a complex number and there is not a unique definition , the first definition for this element would be: the number $x$ which verifies $x^e=-2$ (not uniqu) and this is equivalent to saying that $(-2)^e$ is the element which verifies $e^{e\ln(x)}=-2$ and from here we have to define the function $x\to \ln(x)$ for negative numbers because for positive numbers $x$ $e^{e\ln(x)}>0$ but this is no easy, there is a lot of definitions for logarithms for complex numbers which gives you a lot of definitions of $(-2)^e$

Comment: @Elaqqad Somehow I truly believe that there's a single definite value for (-2)^e, because why not?

Comment: My comment contains some highlights about what I'm thinking (It's not well wrote I agree) but the value is not unique and there is no  only one "acceptable" definition, and I did not write a full answer but If you think a little about the problem you will understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the value of the "number" $(-2)^e$; this is equivalent to considering

$$x=(-2)^e\\
\ln x=e\ln(-2)\\
\frac {\ln x}e=\ln(-2)\\
e^{\frac {\ln x}e}=-2\\
\frac 12e^{\frac {\ln x}e}=-1\\
e^{\frac {\ln x}e+\ln\frac 12}=-1\\
$$

Given the equation $e^{a+bi}=e^a(\cos b+i\sin b)$, we only need to find $x$ such that $\frac {\ln x}e=i\pi+2ni\pi-\ln\frac 12$ or $\ln x=ei\pi+2nei\pi+e\ln 2$ which is
$$x=e^{ei\pi+2nei\pi+e\ln 2}=2^e(\cos(e\pi+2ne\pi)+i\sin(e\pi+2ne\pi)$$
which is an infinite set of unique complex values in a circle of radius $2^e$.

Comment: yes i've already realized that, but I aprreciate your neat proof :)

Comment: If you wish to have a unique "value" associated with such numbers, I might suggest that the form $(-2)^e$ is one such way to communicate the value under discussion.  I'm only guessing here, but if what you are looking for is a different "number system" under which this particular value results in only a single "value" under the system, then you will probably need to start redefining rules before the real numbers, since the complex numbers are a "simple" algebraic extension of the reals...

Comment: Abiessu Yes, that exactly what I'm talking about! :D

Answer (score 1):

The general definition of $a^x$ in complex numbers (for $a \ne 0$) is
$\exp(x \log(a))$, where $\log(a)$ is any branch of the natural logarithm of $a$.  In that sense, $a^x$ will have infinitely many possible values, because you can add any integer multiple of $2 \pi i$ to a value of $\log(a)$ and get another value.  However, if you choose a particular branch of the logarithm to use, that specifies one value that you can think of as **the** value.  For example, a popular choice is the "principal branch": $\text{Log}(a)$ is the branch of $\log(a)$ with imaginary part in the interval $(-\pi, \pi]$.

Thus, e.g., for negative $a$, $\text{Log}(a) = \ln(|a|) + \pi i$, and so
$$a^x = \exp(x \text{Log}(a)) = |a|^x \exp(x \pi i)$$

Caution: many of the standard "laws" of exponents and logarithms are no longer always true for complex numbers.  For example, 
 $\text{Log}(a^x)$ can't be $x \text{Log}(a)$ if the imaginary part of
$x \text{Log}(a)$ is outside the interval $(-\pi, \pi]$.  As a result,
$(a^x)^y$ is not always the same as $a^{xy}$.  A simple example of this:
$(-1)^3 = \exp(3 \pi i) = -1$ so
$$((-1)^{3})^{1/3} = (-1)^{1/3} = \exp(\pi i/3) \ne (-1)^{(3/3)} = -1$$

Comment: The question appears to really be about whether it is possible to redefine the underlying system of numbers such that $\log(a)$ no longer has branches...

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The complex number system $\Bbb C$ helps us handle things like this. Coincidentally, the first example you gave has a solution in the real numbers,  $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What value does $(-2)^e$ have in $\Bbb R$?

Comment: @Sean henderson I don't understand..

Comment: Per @wojowu the second example given does *not* have a solution in the reals...I should have caught that, obviously.